# Looking for help a regex that prevents special characters except ', space and - in the string but disallows them at the start

Tags: angularjs, regex, string, validation

I have been scouring the internet for answers to this regex question and I have come quite close to getting it but I think I am missing one or two more groups to prevent the special characters at the start and end of the string.

It is for use in angularJS and the full specification is a string of letters that cannot be longer than 20 characters, will only allow -,' and space as the special characters but - and ' cannot be consecutively used and cannot be used at the start or end of the string.

Below is the regex I have at the moment:

```
/(?!.*?[ '-]{2})[A-Za-z '-]{1,20}$/
```

It prevents any special characters that are not -' or space and allows only 1 of -' to be used consecutively, However it still allows -and ' at the start and end of the string. The [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/pJ3hJ9/107) displays the regex working.

- -John Doe
- John Doe-
- 'John Doe
- John Doe'

The above 4 need to be flagged as invalid matches but I am unable to figure out how to do that along with all the other expressions that are currently in the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may re-write the pattern to only match 1 non-word char in between lettere, and restrict the length of the regex with a positive lookahead at the start:

```
/^(?=.{1,20}$)[A-Za-z]+(?:[ '-][A-Za-z]+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ND47Pq/1)

NOTE: If you use `maxlength`/`minlength` you can even get rid of the length restriction lookahead.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,20}$)` - the length of the whole string must be from 1 to 20 chars
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:[ '-][A-Za-z]+)?` -  1 optional sequence of:

  - `[ '-]` - 1 space/apostrophe/hyphen
  - `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: That is excellent, thank you. Could you give me a breakdown of the captured groups, positive look ahead and the non capturing group if you have the time to? Could do with understanding them a bit better.

Comment: @P.Doohan There is no [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) here. `(?=.{1,20}$)` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) where `.` matches any char but a line break char, `{1,20}` is a [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) matching 1 to 20 consecutive occurrences of the quantified subpattern and `$` matches the end of string position. The rest is explained, more about [non-capturing groups can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471).